# How does PostgreSQL combine the use of multiple indexes via AND?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, internals, database-engine

How does PostgreSQL combine the use of two btree indexes via the `AND` operator?

I find this page in the Postgres documentation to be highly surprising, to the point of implausibility:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html

This page seems to indicate that when a query contains a clause `WHERE "col1" = 'A' AND "col2" = 'B'`, if both `col1` and `col2` are indexed, then a bitmap (apparently consisting of one bit for every row) is set up in memory for each of the two column indexes, and these are `AND`ed together to find the result set of matching rows.

This seems extremely implausible to me, particularly for btree indexes, because this would mean that query time and memory consumption would both scale linearly in the number of rows in the database, regardless of the number of rows matching a given query, which would make Postgres unusable for many applications.

Please someone tell me that Postgres queries that only sparsely match rows in a table do not scale linearly with the total number of rows in the database!

If two btree indexes index the same table, I would be much more likely to believe that the indexes are combined by somehow intersecting the btree nodes directly (however that would look!). Personally if I were to implement this, I would create a btree containing the unique values in the database, then at each leaf node for each unique value, I would store a heap of the `id` values that have the given value in the indexed column. Finding the common rows would then be quite easy, by intersecting the leaf node heap for each table.

I checked two different Postgres internals docs to see if I can see how this works, and I haven't yet found the answer I'm looking for...

Comment: It CAN combine them it doesn't have to. During the planning stage of the query the planner calculates the cost of many different execution plans and selects the best. Most cases I have seen it will only use a single index per table. You can see the chosen plan by putting explain in front of your query. Note when testing on small databases it tends to execute many queries with a table scan because the extra reads to go through the index are not worth it. So if you want realistic explain results get a copy of a large production database.

Comment: Thanks, that's good practical advice. I don't have enough data to do that yet, I'm just trying to anticipate how this is going to scale. I'm surprised only one index is typically used. I wonder if Postgres would be more likely to use matching partial indices...

Comment: @Eelke Can you please comment on whether this assertion in the doc page is true, that when Postgres uses an index, it creates a bitmap for what sounds like all the rows, and it determines which rows to return based on which bits are set in the bitmap? Again the thing that is so surprising to me is that that would absolutely kill performance for very large tables and very sparse queries.

Comment: The entire text is based on assumptions and you don't have any problem at all. Without a problem, there is nothing to solve. Combining multiple indexes can make your queries lightning fast, also with very large tables. And this also works for OR's, not just AND's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are kind of making up details the documentation intentionally doesn't provide.  Bitmaps are only combined within the same table, and within a table only pages which have rows to contribute are present in the data structure. With the present implementation, each block which contributes any rows takes about 64 bytes. Since they are purely in memory structures, the implementation can change freely between versions.  The docs usually don't go into details on such things, as keeping the docs up to date with changes in implementation is very annoying.

Comment: Thanks, those are exactly the details I needed. So the bitmap size is not linear in the number of rows in the table, it's linear in the number of blocks containing a row in the result set, which means it scales linearly with the size of the result set. That's a relief :-D  Yes, I had to try to read between the lines in the docs, for the reasons you specified. Thanks.